# How to exit the cmd loop of cmd module cleanly

Tags: python, cmd

I'm using the `cmd` module in Python to build a little interactive command-line program. However, from this documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html, it is not clear that what is a clean way to exit the program (i.e. the cmdloop) programmatically.

Ideally, I want to issue some command `exit` on the prompt, and that will exit the program.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to override the `postcmd` method:

> Cmd.postcmd(stop, line)
>
> Hook method executed just after a command dispatch is finished. This
>   method is a stub in Cmd; it exists to be overridden by subclasses.
>   line is the command line which was executed, and stop is a flag which
>   indicates whether execution will be terminated after the call to
>   postcmd(); this will be the return value of the onecmd() method. The
>   return value of this method will be used as the new value for the
>   internal flag which corresponds to stop; returning false will cause
>   interpretation to continue.

And from the `cmdloop` documentation:

> This method will return when the postcmd() method returns a true
>   value. The stop argument to postcmd() is the return value from the
>   command’s corresponding do_*() method.

In other words:

```
import cmd
class Test(cmd.Cmd):
    # your stuff (do_XXX methods should return nothing or False)
    def do_exit(self,*args):
        return True
```

Comment: I wonder if I can just do `def do_exit(self, line): return True`, so that issuing command `exit` will break out the `cmdloop`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is to simply raise and catch a custom Exception.

```py
import cmd

class ExitCmdException(Exception):
    pass #Could do something but just make a simple exception

class myCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    #...
    def do_quit(self, args):
        """ Quits the command loop """
        raise ExitCmdException()

#...
try:
    foo.cmdloop()
except ExitCmdException as e:
    print('Good Bye')
```